# When I was a child/as a child

Tags: sentence-meaning

(Excerpt from native english speakers in a conversation)

> Native A:have you skated before?
>
> Native B: ''I have, a little bit, **as a child**''(edited)

Can I also say:

> ''I have, a little bit, **when I was a child**(edited)

Are they both the same?

Answer (score 1):

Those options are equivalent. They are even very similar grammatically. The response is "I have", because the question was asked in the perfect - "Have you skated?" "I have (skated), a little bit".

The qualification just acts as a prepositional phrase locating the prior occurrence in time.

Answer (score -1):

Grammatically, they are the same.

But as some commenters have pointed out, you wouldn't use "have" here. When you say *as a child*, you imply that you are not a child now. Thus, you should not use the perfect aspect (I have done). Instead, you should use the past (I did):

> I did a little bit when I was a child.

---

Edit:

The distinction between the simple past and the present perfect is subtle. The former is used for actions that have definitively concluded, whereas the latter is used for actions that happened in the past, but may happen again in the present. Compare *I ate yesterday* vs *I have eaten today*. I can still eat again today, but it's impossible for me to eat more yesterday, because yesterday has already ended.

That distinction is why "I skated as a child" and "I have skated, as a child" are *not* exactly the same. "I have skated, as a child" means "I have skated in the past and may skate some more in the present/future, and by the way, I was a child when I skated in the past." The comma turns the "as a child" into an extra detail, not part of the direct response to the question. On the other hand, in "I skated as a child", the "as a child" is part of your answer. It then constrains your answer to the past (you can't become a child again), so you should use the simple past.

Of course, even native speakers like myself don't always get this right, so you're unlikely to catch flak if you use the present perfect when grammar calls for the past.

Comment: Hello, as we can see, the question word was **have** you skated before?, then usually it should be answered with **I have**..., to add, there was the **''as a child''** (time period) right? You better have a good response to this.

Comment: Answer updated. And why are you so hostile?

Comment: I have edited my answer by adding commas, kindly check em' out. This query kinda 'cheeses me off' coz' I am not sure now if my ''comma placement'' is the wrong one here or just the native, adult english speaker's answer(Native B) to the question by the Native A.

Comment: I have [optional comma] a little bit [mandatory comma] (as/when I was) a child. All of the options here are equivalent in meaning, and native speakers don't consistently prefer one over another.

Comment: So you're saying the Native B's answer was incorrect, grammatically?

Comment: @JohnArvin You tell me. Does it match "I have [optional comma] a little bit [mandatory comma] (as/when I was) a child."?